# CSS from code? How to use CSS decoration directly from Vala?

Tags: gtk, gtk3, vala

How to use CSS customization directly from Vala? Not like in this [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28382196/how-can-i-change-the-font-size-of-a-gtk-label-in-vala/28465993#28465993) with file. Let's say I want the button to turn red by clicking on it, without using an external css file, as this action is too simple to create a css file with a single field.

I mean smth like this:

```
label.set_styleSheet("font-size: 17px;")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You still have to create a CssProvider, like in the code you linked to:

```
var screen = this.get_screen ();
var css_provider = new Gtk.CssProvider();
```

You can call `load_from_data ()` instead of `load_from_path ()` to load it from a string in memory instead of a file:

https://valadoc.org/gtk+-3.0/Gtk.CssProvider.load_from_data.html

```
css_provider.load_from_data(".my_class { font-size: 17px; }");
Gtk.StyleContext.add_provider_for_screen(screen, css_provider, Gtk.STYLE_PROVIDER_PRIORITY_USER);
```

When the CSS provider has loaded the custom styles to be used, you can manipulate every Gtk+ widget with `get_style_context ()`.

The style context has methods to add, remove and query a class, etc.

https://valadoc.org/gtk+-3.0/Gtk.StyleContext.html

```
label.get_style_context().add_class("my_class");
```

Since you only have to setup the style provider once, I don't think it is too much overhead.

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer, I'm new to vala, switched from Qt and I have a lot more stupid questions.

Answer (score 1):

For anyone who is reading this I have posted both examples with and without file to Git https://gitlab.com/gavr123456789/vala-css-examples/tree/master

Answer (score 1):

The answer for Gtk-4 (based on [the Jens's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54027003/547270) above):

```
private void apply_css(Gtk.ApplicationWindow window) {
    var provider = new Gtk.CssProvider();
    provider.load_from_resource("/org/example/app/style.css");
    Gtk.StyleContext.add_provider_for_display(
        window.display,  // use display instead of screen
        provider,
        Gtk.STYLE_PROVIDER_PRIORITY_USER);
}
```